# Negative InnoDB Write Log efficiency in mysqltuner.pl results

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, mysqltuner

I noticed something strange in results from mysqltuner.pl.

I see this in mysqltuner output from three of my four servers with MariaDB 10.1.12:

> [OK] You have the latest version of MySQLTuner(1.6.5)
>
> [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.12-MariaDB
>
> [!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: -79.30% (-8928 hits/ 11258 total)

- What does this mean?
- How number of hits can be negative?

**EDIT**

It can be concluded from the contents of mysqltuner.pl script that

> InnoDB Write Log efficiency = (Innodb_log_write_requests -
>   Innodb_log_writes) / Innodb_log_write_requests

It means that InnoDB Write Log efficiency is negative when `innodb_log_writes` is greater than `innodb_log_write_requests`. Still, I don't know what this means in practice.

- Is this bad that `innodb_log_writes` > `innodb_log_write_requests`?
- How should I interpret this "efficiency"?

Comment: What are the numbers for Innodb_log_write_requests and Innodb_log_writes, are they 11258 and 20186? Also, what is the value of innodb_log_buffer_size?

Comment: @Lennart, I've restarted all four db servers, so those values are different now, but still `innodb_log_writes` = 107 is greater than `innodb_log_write_requests` = 55. `innodb_log_buffer_size` is set to 16M.